# handle redirect in K8S cluster in localhost

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway

I have K8S cluster running on my host (docker desktop)
I have 6 components, each of them in it's own deployment.

Each of them has service (Loadbalancer or ClusterIP)

1. Spring API GW (host api-gw on port 8000)
2. Spring eureka server (host service-discovery on port 8001)
3. Order service (host order-service on port 8002)
4. Product Service (host product-service on port 8003)
5. MariaDB (host db on port 3306)
6. PHPMyAdmin (host phpmyadmin on port 8004)

everything work fine while I navigate to localhost:8000

I added keycloak for autn to my system with all configuration in my spring-apigw (acts as oauth2 client)

**keycloak(host kyecloak on port 8005)**

Now, when I navigate to localhost:8000 it direct me to keycloak:8005 (which it's fine).

How can I remain it as `localhost` so it work (without modify my `hosts` file, I know this way it will work)

Does the solution can come from the spring-gw `application.yml` file?

```
server:
  port: 8000

spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://keycloak:8005/auth/realms/myapp
        registration:
          keycloak:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: my-client
            client-secret: *****
            scope:
              - email
              - profile
              - roles

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://service-discovery:8001/eureka
  instance:
    hostname: ${spring.application.name}
```

Or via K8S configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: the issuer url could be the culprint. If this is OIDC, it will discover other endpoints from a path on this url. These endpints will contain the same hostname, and since the users browser is involved, it gets that "internal" hostname while it wants to have ,localhost. It would be easier if you could set the token and auth endpoint in this config, instead of using OIDC. Then you could simply set them to localhost

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
client -> server -> oidc discovery  -> http://keycloack/authorize
```

The place where I say `oidc discovery` refers to this spec, https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/openid-connect-discovery/.

You could, instead of doing OIDC discovery, tell the client the URLs directly.

```
client -> server -> http://localhost/authorize
```

I found this example in a [blog post](https://dev.to/relive27/spring-cloud-gateway-combined-with-the-security-practice-of-oauth20-protocol-1m3b). The solution lies within.

In the below config you can see how the URIs, are set manually instead of only setting the issuer URL and relying on discovery like you do.

```
pring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          messaging-gateway-oidc:
            provider: gateway-client-provider
            client-id: relive-client
            client-secret: relive-client
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope:
              - openid
              - profile
            client-name: messaging-gateway-oidc
        provider:
          gateway-client-provider:
            authorization-uri: http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth2/authorize
            token-uri: http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth2/token
            jwk-set-uri: http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth2/jwks
            user-info-uri: http://127.0.0.1:8080/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: sub
```

This way, you could send the right URL to the user without having to look them up on the discovery endpoint of the issuer.

The ODIC, lookup would result in the same URIs, we see in above example except for having the issuer URLs, hostname. That's exactly what you do not want.

So by setting the URIs manually, you have more control and can set it the way you want.

Just make sure that your ingress controller understands a request without hostname and routes to your oauth2 service.

With URIs, I mean these properties

- authorization-uri: http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth2/authorize
- token-uri: http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth2/token
- jwk-set-uri: http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth2/jwks
- user-info-uri: http://127.0.0.1:8080/userinfo

instead of:

- issuer-uri: http://keycloak:8005/auth/realms/myapp

Note, this is only conceptionally the solution. HOW to do this specific thing with your stack of choice, I don't know, but this is WHAT you have to do.

Comment: `Just make sure that your ingress controller understands a request without hostname and routes to your oauth2 service.` I think this is enough, no? that something that the Spring APIGW can't do with routes?

Comment: @ShayZambrovski, as far as I understand the request would not reach the ingress controller at all currently. Because no DNS has a record for his keycload domain. That is the kubernetes internal service name. So OPs. current workaround is modifying the local hosts file. They want to use localhost instead and for this something needs to send the client the redirect-uri with localhost inside.

Comment: That's what I thought, the `hosts` trick is the only solution, just want to verify it.

Comment: @ShayZambrovski no, its not the only sulution. You can tell your sevice that is sending the redirect uri to the client, to use localhost instead of keycloak. That is what my answer is about.

Comment: @ShayZambrovski, check the update on my answer. In the beginning. I tried to make the problem more clear.

Comment: I see, and the ingress will do the resolving by the path to the right service (aka keycloak)?

Comment: @ShayZambrovski, once you got your app to send localhost as redirect uri, you need to make sure your ingress understand the request when it comes. So you need to do path based routing or have keycloak run on the "default" route.

Comment: Thanks, I hoped that the Spring API GW could do it, apparently no. maybe nginx could do it... thanks anyway!